# How to understand new a Comparable arrray?

Tags: java

**Comparable** is a interface, we can **new** it? Why? I'm a new one in Java. Part of the code is as follows:

```
/**
 * Rearranges the array in ascending order, using the natural order.
 * @param a the array to be sorted
 */
public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
    Comparable[] aux = new Comparable[a.length];
    sort(a, aux, 0, a.length-1);
    assert isSorted(a);
}
```

The class file is [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/Merge.java).  Thank you.

Comment: You're not creating `Comparable`s, you're creating an array that can hold references to `Comparable`s.

Comment: It's been asked many times but still take a quick look https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  I should learn something about generics Array?

Comment: Remember, there are differences between the meanings of the  [/] and the (/) brackets.

Comment: @lxgeek, they call this polymorphism. but yeah, for this, I think first you should understand inheritance and interfaces.

Comment: @lxgeek Hint: try to fully study the basics first. Understand what arrays are, and how they work. Then dive into generics. But don't try to mix concepts before you really understand them on their own. As there are certain restrictions; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays - you cant create an array of a parametrized types for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Oliver Charlesworth said, what you create is an array that itself is not an interfaces. The thing is that you now can create instances of `Comparable` and store them in the array. In order to do this you can either:

1. implement `Comparable` and create instances of the implementation in the array, or
2. create an instance of `Comparable` by utilizing a concept of [Anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

The latter would look something like:

```
aux[0]= new Comparable(){
    public int compareTo(Object o){
        //code that compares this with the Object o
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to understand is: using **new** you create **Objects** (aka reference types). And Objects always have exactly one **class** that "backs" their identity.

But as you probably know, a class can implement various interfaces. So it is perfectly fine to create an array to carry Objects of a class that implements a certain interface. You see, in that sense an interface is a "view" that allows you to deal with certain Objects only looking at one **part** of the functionality that they provide.

In other words: no, you can't create "Objects" from an interface. So, the thingies that you put in that array in your example, in the end are "instances of some class", not "pure instances of an interface" - as the later simply doesn't exist in the Java language. But what you can do is to create an array that contains Objects that all fit into the "Comparable" view.